# In Java, how can I join a LocalDate and a time formatted String into one observable property of LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, javafx, binding, localtime

My attempt is to unify the values of a `DatePicker` (that handles the date selection, but not the time) and a `TextField` (that handles the time) into an observable `LocalDateTime` of both joined.

I've set up observable properties for both in the model, but I am having difficulties joining them.

So far I managed to make a few tries with `Bindings.createObjectBinding()`, but I don't seem to have much success there.

I would like to know at least if I am on the right path or should I go about this differently?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried? I don't completely get what you are trying to achieve... Combining a result of a `DatePicker` (of unkown type so far) and a `String` seems possible, but I have no idea about the observable part.

Comment: Do you mean *into an observable Local**Date**Time*?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I will edit.

Comment: @deHaar, I edited my question to provide the data types. Does that help? My code is a bit scattered across several classes, if need be, I will attempt to create a minimal viable demo later on.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it should be something in the lines of this: startDateTime.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> LocalDateTime.of(dateStartInput.getValue(), LocalTime.parse(timeStartInput.valueProperty().getValue()))));

Comment: `dateStartInput.getValue()` is no `LocalDate`, you have to parse it first like `LocalDate.parse(dateStartInput.getValue(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)` for example. Because `LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate, LocalTime)`...

Comment: My answer assumes you're using JavaFX based on the classes and methods you mention in your question (which is also why I added the [tag:javafx] tag). If that assumption is incorrect please let me know and [edit] your question to clarify what technologies you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`LocalDateTime#of(LocalDate,LocalTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalTime)) you can create a `LocalDateTime` from a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime`. What you need now is a way to get an instance of both a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime`. Fortunately, the `DatePicker` control gives you its value as a `LocalDate` so we're done there. Next is finding a way to get a `LocalTime` from a `TextField`. This is possible by using a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) and a [`StringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/util/StringConverter.html) which knows how to convert a `String` to a `LocalTime` and vice versa. There's a built-in `StringConverter` for this use case: [`LocalTimeStringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/util/converter/LocalTimeStringConverter.html).

Once we have both the `DatePicker` and the `TextFormatter` we need to create a binding which creates a `LocalDateTime` from the two values. Since both `DatePicker` and `TextFormatter` have a `value` property, which holds a `LocalDate` and, in this case, a `LocalTime`, respectively, creating the binding is relatively simple with [`Bindings#createObjectBinding(Callable,Observable...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createObjectBinding(java.util.concurrent.Callable,javafx.beans.Observable...)).

```java
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
// Have to associate the TextFormatter with a TextField
TextFormatter<LocalTime> tf = new TextFormatter<>(new LocalTimeStringConverter());

ObjectBinding<LocalDateTime> binding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    LocalDate ld = dp.getValue();
    LocalTime lt = tf.getValue();
    return ld == null || lt == null ? null : LocalDateTime.of(ld, lt);
}, dp.valueProperty(), tf.valueProperty());
```

Here's a full example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.LocalTimeStringConverter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());

    TextField timeField = new TextField();
    TextFormatter<LocalTime> timeFieldFormatter =
        new TextFormatter<>(new LocalTimeStringConverter());
    timeField.setTextFormatter(timeFieldFormatter);
    timeFieldFormatter.setValue(LocalTime.now());

    HBox dateTimeBox = new HBox(10, datePicker, timeField);
    dateTimeBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    ObjectBinding<LocalDateTime> ldtBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
      LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
      LocalTime time = timeFieldFormatter.getValue();
      return date == null || time == null ? null : LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
    }, datePicker.valueProperty(), timeFieldFormatter.valueProperty());

    Label ldtLabel = new Label();
    ldtLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
      LocalDateTime dateTime = ldtBinding.get();
      return dateTime == null ? null : dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    }, ldtBinding));

    VBox root = new VBox(15, dateTimeBox, ldtLabel);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(25));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

The above binds the text of a `Label` to the `ObjectBinding<LocalDateTime>`. The value of the `TextFormatter` will update whenever the text is "committed" (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the `TextField` has focus).

The way I constructed the `LocalTimeStringConverter` means it will use my `Locale` and `FormatStyle.SHORT` for both parsing and formatting the `LocalTime`. As an example, for me that means something like `3:30 PM` or `11:25 AM`. This is customizable—see the various constructors of `LocalTimeStringConverter`.